# return referrer or refresh after process download in Yii2 doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2

I want to refresh my page to update view of data after downloading a file, and if i use a variable to process download then back to referrer it doesn't work. I'm confused because i can't use `return` twice, how to solve it?

my code in controller:

```
if (file_exists($root)) {
     // here's the problem:
     return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($root, $profile['resumefilename']);   //download resume
     return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);   // i can't put return here, but i need to refresh page after download
} else {
     Yii::$app->session->setFlash('failed', 'Data resume is not found!');
     return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question using jquery and it works. I still use `sendFile( )` to process download then add some code in js. This is my code:

```
//this is my controller
if (file_exists($file)) {
     // here's the problem:
     return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file, $profile['resumefilename']);
} else {
     Yii::$app->session->setFlash('failed', 'Data resume is not found!');
     return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

here's in view:

```
<a class="dropdown-item btn-download" href="your_link">Download</a>
```

here's jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-download', function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    location.reload(true);
  },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This **cannot be done on the server side**, the limitation comes from how HTTP works, one request gets one response.

You cannot send the file as the `200` response **and** send a `302` redirect response, it has to be one **or** the other.

Since you are redirecting the user to the same page both on success and error, it would be easy to do the same from the client side.

The most common way, probably also the easiest way, would be to add the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute to your link:

```php
Html::a('download file', 
    ['file/download', 'id' => $model->id], 
    ['download' => $model->name]
);
```

That would initiate the file download, but the user would not navigate away from the page they are on.

You could also intercept the click and use JavaScript to manage the download and show any information that you want, download progress, error notification and such.